# Snowflake SQL stored procedure and save value from query to variable

Tags: sql, scripting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a SQL stored procedure in Snowflake (language SQL NOT Javascript). I pass in a database name and I have a cursor to get all schemas for that database. I loop through them one by one and am creating a new role and then doing a bunch of other things related to granting permissions. If the role already exists I want to skip that schema and continue on to the next schema.

I am having a hard time determining if the role exists. FYI, I am doing `CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS name_of_schema`...  However, I do not want to continue on to the rest of the code if the role exists because some of the code will fail such as granting future grants.

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to do something like `IF EXISTS ROLE name of role`...

I could query the snowflake.account_usage.roles view but that can be delayed 2 hours and the role could have been created in less time but if that is my only option I would have to live with it.  I think I could use the result_scan function...something like this and the status would contain the words " already exists, statement succeeded."

```
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS  <role name>;
query := 'SELECT status FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()));';
```

However, I don't know how to get the value of status into a variable where I can then check to see if it is LIKE '%already exists%'.

Can anyone provide guidance or give me an example?  I think I could probably put this in a cursor and then loop to accomplish this.  That seems like a lot of code to retrieve a value.  It seems like I should be able to capture a value from a query into a variable when only one row would be returned.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html#using-string-constant-delimiters-around-a-block-in-a-stored-procedure), you can use Snowflake Scripting within a SQL procedure.

And Snowflake scripting can use [conditionals](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html)

So you would have something like this. I used a table creation instead, but it's the exact same idea:

```sql
create or replace procedure myprocedure()
  returns int
  language sql
  as
  $$
    DECLARE
        status string;
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(i int);
        status := (SELECT "status" FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id())));
        
        IF (status LIKE '%already exists%') THEN
            RETURN 1;
        ELSE
            RETURN 2;
        END IF;
    END;
$$;
```

sidenote: the `$$` are needed in the classic web interface, but you may not need them.

Comment: I do also feel like there's a better way to switch on whether or not a role exists, other than using the result scan like this. But nothing's coming immediately to mind.

Comment: I agree it seems like there should be a better way to check if a role exists than actually trying to create it and capture the result text.  However, this worked for me so thank you!